# How do I separate the columns imported from an excel spreadsheet in order to create multiple separate lists

Tags: r, list

I imported a spreadsheet into R and wound up with this:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("C:\\Users\\wsu\\Downloads\\Massachusetts Infections by County, Population Density, and Daily Temperature (Statistics Begin 3_9_20).xlsx",sheet="Sheet1")
                                                                             
New names:
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
* `` -> ...6
* ...
# A tibble: 51 x 15
   `Infections per~ ...2  ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10 ...11
   <chr>            <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 
 1 "Time (in Days)~ Suff~ Midd~ Norf~ Essex Bris~ Hamp~ Worc~ Plym~ Hamp~ Barn~
 
 2 "1"              10    15    10    0     0     0     1     0     0     0    
 3 "2"              20    41    22    1     0     0     1     0     0     0    
 4 "3"              19    44    23    1     0     0     1     0     0     0    
 5 "4"              22    49    24    2     0     0     1     0     0     0    
 6 "5"              26    60    24    2     0     0     2     0     0     0    
 7 "6"              27    65    28    5     1     0     2     0     0     1    
 8 "7"              31    75    31    6     1     1     6     1     0     1    
 9 "8"              36    83    36    8     2     1     6     3     0     1    
 10 "9"              42    89    43    8     5     1     8     5     0     2    
# ... with 41 more rows, and 4 more variables: ...12 <chr>, ...13 <chr>,
#   ...14 <chr>, ...15 <chr>
```

Now, in order to create lists for use in an exponential regression, I need to split each column of this table into different lists saved under separate names.  There are 50 numbers in each column to be put into a list.  How might I go about programming this?

Comment: Hi Total, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think it will be challenging to answer your question because it's not clear. In R, regressions are typically performed on `data.frame` class objects rather than lists, which you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can act on column vectors of a dataframe.  Why do you want to break it out?  If you actually do want separate vectors you can get those with lapply.  mtcars example:

```
ncols <- ncol(mtcars)
ncols
11
veclist <- lapply(1:ncols, function(x) mtcars[ , x])
veclist
[[1]]
 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5
[22] 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

[[2]]
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

[[3]]
 [1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0
[18]  78.7  75.7  71.1 120.1 318.0 304.0 350.0 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0

[[4]]
 [1] 110 110  93 110 175 105 245  62  95 123 123 180 180 180 205 215 230  66  52  65  97 150 150 245 175  66
[27]  91 113 264 175 335 109
```

Comment: My point of wanting to break out the vectors was just to have several saved separately for some exponential regressions I was making; I needed Time separate to reuse in conjunction with each of the other columns